# Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Tags: android, react-native

After running the `react-native doctor` command on the terminal of Visual Studio Code for React Native app it gives
`✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android`

Android Studio is already installed on Windows 10 and working properly for Android native apps.
Can I change the path of Android Studio in React Native setup?

Comment: Found solution steps are : 

1) - In Project folder >android >app >gradle >gradle-wrapper.properties
Replace distributionUrl with given line  
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip  
2) - In android >app >gradle.properties  
Add this line (your JDK version compatible with react native version)  
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_74  
3) - Update, if you have npm v5, use npx:
`npx rimraf ./**/node_modules`  
Otherwise install RimRaf:  
`npm install rimraf -g`  
4) - install npm by `npm install`

Answer (score 11):

For those who get the following error:

```
Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
```

I solve it by installing `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)`
in Android Studio > Tools > SDK Manager > SDK tools > Android SDK Command-line Tools.

Additional resources that may help:
https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2022/11/01/fix-react-native-doctor-android-errors/
https://developer.android.com/tools/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. Mine was even showing that:

```
    Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android   
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 29.0.3
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   2
Warnings: 0 
Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.
```

[image]

I got fed up with all the steps that are online that are not working and just clicked on 'e'.
It took its time and installed the said missing programs (note that I already installed Android studio and all the SDK instructions on react-native docs before now but for some reason it was not being detected)

When I ran `npx react-native doctor`, the issue was resolved:

[image]

**Note that this may consume some amount of bandwidth since it is re-downloading Android studio and all other dependencies(maybe everything should be about 2GB of data), and a strong internet connection is recommended.**

Comment: i have my setup so that i only have windows on a drive and i use other drives to store all my programs and data. this will not work for me, sadly.

Comment: I tried using the e option from the `npx react-native doctor`.  After it was done it said ` Android SDK configured. You might need to restart your PC for all changes to take effect.`  I immediately tried running `npx react-native doctor` and got the `Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android   - Versions found N/A` error again.  I rebooted and reran  `npx react-native doctor`  but it still can't find the Android SDK.

Comment: Pressing e worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**Linux**:

Ensure you have android-studio installed on default folder `/opt/android-studio` & your android-studios's executable file will be something like `/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`.