# Android Studio and SDK not detected by React Native | Both are existing in the system (downloaded and installed)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I have installed all the requirements and have added the paths to the environment as well, I am still getting the issue for SDK and Android Studio... I have added the path and all the necessary.

I have installed the SDK version as mentioned by the react-native doctor

Also, I installed the Android Studio recently in the d drive of the system

ANDROID_HOME has the same path as the SDK and that passed the check ... I am not able to figure out why it's showing like this...

OS: Windows

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht0Ev.png)

I have installed the exact version for sdk

Comment: Check this - 
[Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481399/android-studio-required-for-building-and-installing-your-app-on-android)